# How to install TCL 8.5 on Centos 5.8?

Tags: centos, tcl

Soooo, the latest redis requires tcl 8.5 (a few weeks ago, redis was happy with tcl 8.4).

Is there an rpm for tcl 8.5?

thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CentOS 6 has TCL 8.5.7. Probably time to retire those CentOS 5 beasts.

Comment: Oy, I thought it WAS Centos 6x....  It is actually 5.8... how can I get tcl 8.5x on it?  Thx!

Comment: is there no way to do it in 5.x?I cant probably reinstall my server